# How to make n consecutive elements from list by lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

For example, I have:
list = ['hello how is your day', 'what do you think about it']
and we have a number n (amount of consecutive elements)?

For example n=2, I want to get: ['hello how', 'how is', 'is your', 'your day', 'what do', 'do you', 'you think', 'think about', 'about it']

I want to use lambda function: list(map(lambda x: ..., list)) 
I understand that in ... must be x.split()
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a sliding window. I'd use itertools and be lazy about it with a window function. [recipe from old python version](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html)

```py
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

sentences = ['hello how is your day', 'what do you think about it']

res = [" ".join(words) for words in window((word for sentence in sentences for word in sentence.split()))]
```

```
['hello how',
 'how is',
 'is your',
 'your day',
 'day what',
 'what do',
 'do you',
 'you think',
 'think about',
 'about it']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['hello how is your day', 'what do you think about it']
list_consecutive =[]
n=3

#working on each element of list one by one
for i in list:
  sp = i.split()
  count = 0
  
  while count < (len(sp)-n+1):
    #variable to store the word pair eg. 'hello how is'
    word_pair = ''

    #making pair according to value of 'n'
    for j in range(0,n):
      word_pair += sp[count+j]+' '


    #remove extra space from end
    word_pair = word_pair[0:-1]
    
    #appending the created word pair to list
    list_consecutive.append(word_pair)
    count+=1
print(list_consecutive)
```

OUTPUT

```
['hello how is', 'how is your', 'is your day', 'what do you', 'do you think', 'you think about', 'think about it']
```